# Genetic Algorithm optimization in C++

Tags: c++, optimization, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I'm looking for effective means of adding or omitting code in order to help my genetic algorithm program return faster results. The goal of the program is to accept a string and create other strings that match as closely as possible. Whichever newly made strings match the closest(the top 5) mate with others and produces offspring(some of which have mutations that put a new random number into the string without affecting the length). It all works fine, but it takes an unfathomable amount of generations to get some of the longer strings(4 and up) to perfectly match. 
Sorry about the tl;dr length, but here's my current code. Criticize away!

```
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "fstream"
    #include "ctime"
    #include "iostream"
    #include "string"
    #include "windows.h"

    #define CHARACTERS 16
    #define STRINGS 100
    /*
    Enter String(max 16 chars)
    Generate 100 words of the same length
    Check for Fitness(how close each word is to the string)
    Every generation: display top 5
    Clone the top 5
    Top 20 reproduce(mix each other's chars)
    1/1000 chance the children might mutate(each newly mixed string or char might have a completely random number)

    */

    typedef struct _stringHolder
    {
        char randString[CHARACTERS];
        int fitness;
    }StringHolder;


//Randomly generate 100 words
void generate(char *myString, StringHolder *SH)
{
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);
        //int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char randChar;
        //char showString[CHARACTERS];
    for(int i=0; i<STRINGS; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<strlen(myString); j++)
        {
            randChar = ('a' + (rand() %26));
            SH[i].randString[j] = randChar;
        }
        //limiter so that it doesn't crash
        SH[i].randString[strlen(myString)] = 0;
    }
}

//Check the similarity of the random strings to the original string.
void getFitness(char *myString, StringHolder *SH)
{
    for(int i=0; i<STRINGS; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<strlen(myString); j++)
        {
            if(SH[i].randString[j] == myString[j])
            { SH[i].fitness++; }
        }
    }
}

//Sort the strings
void sortByFitness(char *myString, StringHolder *SH)
{

        bool swapped = 1;
        while(swapped)
        {
            swapped = 0;
            for(int a=0; a<STRINGS-1; a++)
            {
                if(SH[a].fitness < SH[a+1].fitness)
                {
                    swapped = 1;


                        StringHolder temp[STRINGS]; 
                        temp[a] = SH[a+1]/*.randString[i]*/;
                        SH[a+1]/*.randString[i]*/ = SH[a]/*.randString[i]*/;
                        SH[a]/*.randString[i]*/ = temp[a];

                    /*if(SH[a].fitness < SH[a+1].fitness)
                    { swapped = 0; }*/
                }
            }
        }//while
}

//Clone the Top 5 strings
void cloneTopFive(char *myString, StringHolder *SH, StringHolder *cloneString)
{
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {       
            cloneString[i]/*.randString[j]*/ = SH[i]/*.randString[j]*/;
            //printf("cloneString[%d] now holds %s.\n", i, SH[i].randString);

    }
}
//Reproduce the Top 20 strings by mixing and matching elements between strings
void reproduceTopTwenty(char *myString, StringHolder *SH /*char *cloneString*/)
{
    /*for(int h=5; h<95; h++)
    {*/
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<strlen(myString)-1; j++)
            {
                //char temp[16];
                //temp[i] = 
                SH[i].randString[j] = SH[1 + (rand() %20)].randString[1 + (rand() %strlen(myString)-1)];
                int randomNumber;
                randomNumber = (1 +(rand() %100));
                if(randomNumber == 7)
                {
                    SH[i].randString[1 + (rand() %strlen(myString)-1)] = ('a' + (rand() %26));
                }
            }
        }

}
//Randomize the other 75 numbers and place the cloned Top 5 at the end of the String Holder(SH)
void randomizeOther75(char *myString, StringHolder *SH, StringHolder *cloneString)
{
    for(int i=20; i<STRINGS; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<strlen(myString); j++)
        {
            SH[i].randString[j] = ('a' + (rand() %26));
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<strlen(myString); j++)
        {
            int v = i + 94;
            SH[v].randString[j] = cloneString[i].randString[j];
        }
    }

}
void printGen(char *myString, StringHolder *SH)
{
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {       
            if(SH[i].fitness == strlen(myString))
             { printf("%s has %d fitness. Perfection!\n", SH[i].randString, SH[i].fitness); }
            else
             printf("%s has %d fitness.\n", SH[i].randString, SH[i].fitness);
        }
}
void main()
{
    char myString[CHARACTERS];
    StringHolder cloneString[5];
    StringHolder SH[STRINGS];
    for(int i=0; i<STRINGS; i++)
    { SH[i].fitness = 0; }

    printf("Enter your name(no whitespaces): ");
    scanf("%s", myString);
    /*while(strlen(myString) >= CHARACTERS)
    {
        printf("Please type a string with less than 16 characters\n");
        scanf("%s", myString);
    }*/
    //printf("%s\n", myString);

    //first generation
    generate(myString, SH);
    int gen = 0;
    while(1)
    {   
        char x = ' ';
    /*  printf("Insert something. Anything!");
        scanf(&x);*/


        /*char newString[CHARACTERS];
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            for( int j=0; j< strlen(myString); j++)
            {           
                newString[j] = SH[i].randString[j]; 
            }
            newString[strlen(myString)] = 0;
            printf("%s has %d fitness.\n", newString, SH[i].fitness);
        }*/

        printf("\n");
        while(x==' ')
        {
            printf("Generation %d: \n", gen);
            getFitness(myString, SH);
            sortByFitness(myString, SH);

            printGen(myString, SH);

            for(int i=0; i<STRINGS; i++)
            { SH[i].fitness = 0; }

            cloneTopFive(myString, SH, cloneString);
            reproduceTopTwenty(myString, SH);
            randomizeOther75(myString, SH, cloneString);
            /*getFitness(myString, SH);
            sortByFitness(myString, SH);

            for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            {
                printf("%s has %d fitness.\n", SH[i].randString, SH[i].fitness);
            }
            printf("\n");*/

            //printf("\nInsert ' ' to continue!\n");

            //scanf("%c",&x);
            gen++;
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One of the big reasons for the GA to converge poorly is your fitness function. Disregarding potential coding errors in other parts of the programm, what you do is rewarding only perfectly matched letters. The fitness landscape is like this (fear my ASCII art!):

```
___________   ___________
           | |
           |_|
a b c d e f G h i j k l m
```

Where G is the desired letter. The algorithm has no clue how to find G but through sheer luck. You've basically implemented a randomized letter-wise brute-force search.

Make the fitness function reward "closeness" to the correct solution and convergence will be much faster. Also tweak population parameters, mutation, crossover etc.

Comment: "Make the fitness function reward "closeness" to the correct solution and convergence will be much faster": Not necessarily...it depends on whether your operators have the same concept of "distance" or not. From the code, I'm not convinced that they do. If the mutation operator is changed to add or subtract one from a character value then yes, this answer is correct. If mutation chooses a new random value then this answer is incorrect. GAs are tricky!

Comment: From a closer reading of the code I'm increasingly convinced that this will *not* work. Crossover chooses from random parent alleles, and mutation is essentially non-existant (rather, the bottom 75 individuals are randomly generated). There is no mechanism as it stands to do any kind of gradient descent on a single allele, so changing the fitness function in this way will do basically nothing. I won't downvote because the *idea* is good, but in this case it also needs a modification to the genetic operators.

Comment: I have to agree with both the answer and the comment. Tweaking your fitness function to reward based on distance from the original as opposed to just taking the Hamming distance might help, although it would mean altering your mutation function to increment or decrement a character by a small amount, rather than just choosing another character randomly.

Answer (score 0):

For each individual most areas of the algorithm (such as fitness evaluation) can be executed independently. For some really great speedups I'd recommend executing these in parallel, [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) is a good architecture this.

Comment: I wish I knew more to be able to do something like CUDA. I'm still more of a novice programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the nature of genetic algorithms means that sometimes you just need to tweak parameters and see if you can make it find a solution faster. Try cloning the top 10 individuals, or the top 7, or the top 3. Change your top 20 to (e.g.) 50. Increase or decrease the mutation rate.

Sadly we do not yet understand enough about the GA to be able to determine "correct" parameters without this kind of tweaking.

Code optimisation is a whole separate question which could make each generation run faster, but I suspect the problem you're having is that it is taking too many generations so I won't speak to that.

Comment: Exactly. I meant to reduce the amount of generations it takes to get the "perfect" answer.

Comment: If you think the answer is wrong then please explain. It will help everybody!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the parameters of your GA. Your population is far too small for such simple computations. You shouldn't have any trouble bumping it up to at least 1000, if not 10 or 100K. You simply don't have enough solutions in the pool to converge to a good result quickly.

In addition your elitism (the number of candidates you clone for the next generation) is rather high. You generally don't want to go above 2% for elitism.

You might also look at how you're doing your crossover function. You generally want to perform crossover for the whole population, rather than just the top 20%. Pass all 95 of your non-cloned values into your crossover function and you will see more diversity in your population.

As Cameron said, your issues likely lie in your parameters rather than your code, and that is a completely different issue, but this should help you on your way. Good luck!

Comment: The fact of the matter is, I was specifically assigned to have the Top 20.

Comment: Large population *may* help, but it's worth looking at the wealth of literature on small population evolutionary algorithms, too. Can you cite a reference for the 2% thing? It's another parameter that must be tuned. 2% will work sometimes, 0.2% or 20% will work in other cases. I agree with the "cross everything" bit. As a blatent advertisement: take a look at Skinner *et al* in regards to the use of mutation to find new genetic material :)

Comment: The reference comes from the work of Drs M. Peterson and F. Moore, both originally out of Wright State, as well as personal experience from my own EC research. It's probably a little wordy, but worth the read IMO. And as you point out, it's not a hard and fast rule, it's just like tuning any other controller, but I can't recall a GA I've used where I gotten positive performance by increasing the elitism above that.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not familiar with their work, but I haven't done a lot of steady-state stuff. Certainly in generational GAs the choice of elitism parameter is highly problem and representation dependent (just like all the other parameters). I'll have a read.